# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\sin(n)|/n$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prove that $ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N} } | \frac{\sin( n)}{n} | $ diverges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264980/how-to-prove-that-sum-n-in-mathbbn-frac-sin-nn-diverges)

Does the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|\sin(n)|}{n}$ converge or diverge? (And why?)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Both you and the site would benefit if you would consider [registering your account.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) Also, if you find answers helpful, up vote them. If you find a "best answer", accept it by clicking on the check mark under the question.

Comment: Sorry guys...I did look believe it or not!

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/70615) also covers this result.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $|\sin{x}| \geqslant {\dfrac{1}{2}}$ for $x \in I_k=\left[{\dfrac{\pi}{6}}+k\pi, \;\;\pi-{\dfrac{\pi}{6}}+k\pi \right].$ Length of every $I_k$ 
$$|I_k|=\pi-{\dfrac{2\pi}{6}}={\dfrac{2\pi}{3}}>2,$$
so  *every*  $I_k$ contains *at least one*  natural number $n_k.$

Then  $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \dfrac{|\sin(n)|}{n} \geqslant {\dfrac{1}{2}}\sum\limits_{n_k\leqslant{N}} \dfrac{1}{n_k} \underset{N\to\infty}{\to}{\infty}$$ since the harmonic series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: This is not correct. You need $1/n_k$ in your sum, and there is no easy way to show that the "thinned out" version of the harmonic series diverges. (What happens if $n_k = 2^k$?)

Comment: @mrf $|\sin{x}| \geqslant {\dfrac{1}{2}}$ for $x \in I_k=\left[{\dfrac{\pi}{6}}+k\pi, \;\;\pi-{\dfrac{\pi}{6}}+k\pi \right].$ Length of every $I_k$ 
$$|I_k|=\pi-{\dfrac{2\pi}{6}}={\dfrac{2\pi}{3}}>2,$$
so, _every_ $I_k$ contains _at least one_ natural number $n_k.$

Comment: Yes, but that is quite far from what you wrote first.

Comment: @mrf Thanks for pointing of my inaccuracy